# How to Include the Dollar Sign for a Sum in a Report

Tags: reporting, sum

I've created a number of reports that sum up expenses by day and by type of expense. Each of the individual amounts show up with a dollar sign, however, the sum does not. The formula I used is:

```
Expense_Tracker__c.Amount__c:SUM
```

How do I get the dollar sign included in the Sum?